# Why can't I get the expression for this karnaugh map using minterms?

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

[image]

I am getting ab + bc'd' + ab'c', But I keep failing, it doesn't work for my table.

[image]

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong? This is using minterms.

Answer (score 4):

There is firstly a mistake, it is not \$ab'c'\$ but \$ab'c\$. And you also have to keep in mind that the table rolls in the edges (both left/right AND bottom/top), so that the two lower 1's can be grouped with the two upper 1's. The last term \$ab'c\$ can then be further reduced to \$ac\$. Finally you forgot one 1 alone, which is \$a'b'c'd\$.

Answer (score 0):

The four end corners combine to give 'ac'.

The upper four(ab) and the duplet(bc'd') are correct in yours.
All 1's are covered.
Hence =ab+ac+bc'd'